# Update multiple records at once in asp.net mvc with tag-helpers and selectListItem

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, tag-helpers

Starting with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30401500/update-multiple-records-at-once-in-asp-net-mvc?answertab=votes#tab-top), I'm a bit puzzled on how to implement it using a select list and tag-helpers in the view. Where would the `[i]` index go for `<select asp-for="RoleId" asp-items="Model.Roles"></select>`? I have a dropdown box for each row of my table, and I need to uniquely identify each dropdown. Right now I'm using razor syntax for the other table rows as in the answer I used above, but for this, I'd prefer do it the tag-helpers way. TIA

Comment: What is your model (is it `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` contains `RoleID`)? In which case `asp-for="[i].RoleId"`

Comment: Yes, I have the data types right, as it works when I use the @Html razor syntax...it's just the placement of the index. I thought of escaping it with `@` but that produces errors.