# Update a Model multiple records .net core 2

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

Getting No Post back result. [See Screen Shot details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfM59.png)

```
    [HttpPost]
    //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> EditList(IEnumerable<EmployeeModel> employeeModels)
    {
            foreach (EmployeeModel emp in employeeModels)
            {
                _context.Update(emp);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));

    }
```

Comment: call `await _context.SaveChangesAsync();` after the loop has finished.

Comment: it ok, Main problem is not getting update model collection in employeeModels.

Comment: Solved dissucess issues berifly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30401500/update-multiple-records-at-once-in-asp-net-mvc